# field error with binding when using thymeleaf form and pass to controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a `Reddit-clone` with `spring-mvc` which has a link and comment entity.

The problem is adding a new comment function.

When I try to submit the form, In my controller, the `bindingResult` has an error.

The log info showed that there is a Field error in object '`comment`' on-field '`link`'. The error is due to `type mismatch` from String to Link.

I couldn't figure out where the String comes from and why the link field is not bound correctly.

**A Link and an empty Comment with an association to the link** was added to the model with `get mapping` for the current view page

I'm new to spring and being struggled for this, I appreciate any help.

Below is the code for `controller` and `thymeleaf` as well as my link and comment entity

```
@GetMapping("/link/{id}")
public String read(@PathVariable Long id,Model model) {
        Optional<Link> optionalLink = linkRepository.findById(id);
        if( optionalLink.isPresent() ) {
            Link link = optionalLink.get();
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setLink(link);
            model.addAttribute("comment",comment);
            model.addAttribute("link",link);
}

@PostMapping("/link/comments")
public String addComment(Comment comment, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    log.info(comment.toString());
    if( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
        log.info(bindingResult.toString());
        log.info("Something went wrong.");
    } else {
        log.info("New Comment Saved!");
        commentRepository.save(comment);
    }
    return "redirect:/link/" + comment.getLink().getId();
}
```

```
<form id="frmAddComment" method="POST" th:action="@{/link/comments}" th:object="${comment}">
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{link}"/>
      <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" th:field="*{body}"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

```
@Entity
@Getter@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Comment extends Auditable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @NonNull
    private String body;

    @ManyToOne
    @NonNull
    private Link link;
}
```

```
public class Link extends Auditable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NonNull @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a title")
    private String title;

    @NonNull @URL(message = "Please enter a valid url")
    private String url;

    // comments
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "link")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add the code for `Comment` and `Link` ? At the very least, you will need to return the name of the Thymeleaf template again when `bindingResult` has errors. The redirect should only be done on the happy path.

Comment: Hi, I added code for comment and link. The bindingResult is not expected to have errors. I want to remain on the view page of the current link without a new comment if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML only works with Strings. The problem is that Spring does not know how to convert from a String to a `Link`.

It is easier to create a dedicated form data object and use that in our `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`.

```
public class AddCommentToLinkFormData {
    private long linkId;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1,max=1000) // Set this to the values you want
    private String comment;

    // add getters and setters 
}
```

In your controller:

```
public class MyController {
    
    @GetMapping("...") // URL that you want to use
    public String linkInfo(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("formData", new AddCommentToLinkFormData());
        return "..." // name of your Thymeleaf view
    }

    @PostMapping("/link/comments")
    public String addComments(Model model,
                  @Valid @ModelAttribute("formData") AddCommentToLinkFormData formData,
                  BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
            return "..." // name of your Thymeleaf view. Use `#fields.hasErrors('comment')` in your HTML if you want to show a message if the comment String is not valid.
        } else {
            service.addCommentToLink(formData.getLinkId(), formData.getComment());
            return "redirect:/link/" + formData.getLinkId();
        }
   }
}
```

The HTML should be:

```
<form id="frmAddComment" method="POST" th:action="@{/link/comments}" th:object="${formData}">
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{linkId}"/>
      <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" th:field="*{comment}"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your controller should be like this

@PostMapping("/link/comments")
public String add(Model model,
                  @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "commentForm") CommentForm commentForm,
                  BindingResult bindingResult,
                  RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
        //
    }else{
        //
    }
    return "redirect:/link/" + comment.getLink().getId();
}
```

your CommentForm.java class should have a string field comment and Link type field link.

```
public class CommentForm {

   
    @NotEmpty
    private String comment;

    @NotNull
    private Link link;
}
```

in your HTML access link vlaue like this in hidden filed

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="*{link}"/>

or

<input type="hidden" th:value="*{link.?id}"/>
```

Comment: In my comment class, I have a String body. Using th:field successfully passed the body of comment to the controller. But it failed to bind the link field to the comment class and I don't know why. Using th:text for the body of the comment gives null in the controller for comment.body.

Comment: try to add the value of link in HTML or if that fails try to use id and then fetch link value in backend with the id value that you get from HTML.

Comment: yeah, I used link id and used it to find the link in the backend. It seems only th:object can get the object. th: field would convert it into String. Thank you!