# spring boot + thymeleaf: ... fails to display errors, automatic transition to Login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a registration page.  The field data is validated. When errors are captured in the controller's method for user registration and the registration page is called again (where errors should be displayed), an automatic redirect to the **/login** URL occurs.

> org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [ERROR] 19:34:25 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/account/register.html]")] with root cause
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userData' available as request attribute
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926)

```yaml
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    enabled: true
    check-template-location: true
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    mode: HTML
    cache: false
    encoding: UTF-8
    suffix: .html

logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%C{1.yaml.} [%-5level] %d{HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n'
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        sql: debug
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: trace

      springframework:
        web:
          client: trace
        security: trace
```

- Registrationcontroller

```java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(final Model model){
        UserDataDto user = new UserDataDto();

        model.addAttribute("userData", user);
        return "account/register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String userRegistration(final @Valid UserDataDto userData,
                                   final BindingResult bindingResult,
                                   final Model model){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

            model.addAttribute("errors", userData);
            return "account/register";
        }
        try {
            userService.register(userData);
        }catch (UserAlreadyExistException e){
            
            bindingResult.rejectValue(
                    "email",
                    "userData.email",
                    "An account already exists for this email."
            );
            model.addAttribute("formreg", userData);
            return "account/register";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

- LoginPageController

```java
@Controller
public class LoginPageController {

    @GetMapping("/login-error")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("login")
    public String getLogin(){
        return "account/login";
    }
}
```

- dto

```java
public class UserDataDto {

    @NotEmpty(message = "First name can not be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name can not be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Email can not be empty")
    @Email(message = "Please provide a valid email id")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password can not be empty")
    private String password;

  ...
}
```

- security config

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

- account/register.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Test it -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body class="hold-transition register-page">
<div class="register-logo">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body register-card-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg"></p>

            <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${userData}" method="post">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
                    <ul>
                        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.allErrors()}" th:text="${err}" />
                    </ul>
                </div>
              <!--  <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                    <p th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></p>
                </div>-->
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name"
                           th:errorclass="is-invalid">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name"
                           th:errorclass="is-invalid">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email"
                           th:errorclass="is-invalid">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password"
                           th:errorclass="is-invalid">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype password">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:150px" ;>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary  btn-sm btn-block">Register</button>
                </div>

                <div></div>
                <p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="icheck-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms" name="terms" value="agree">
                            <label for="agreeTerms">
                                I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->

                </div>
                </p>

                <!-- /.col -->
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="login" class="text-center">I already have an Account</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.form-box -->
</div><!-- /.card -->
</div>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- account/login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Test it -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
 </head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
                <p th:if="${loginError}" class="error">Wrong user or password</p>
                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                    <div th:if="${param.error}">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            Invalid username or password.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Ionicons
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">-->
<!-- icheck bootstrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

- pom.xml

```xml
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 ....
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I tried that:

- controller

```java
@GetMapping("/handleLoginErrors")
    ModelAndView handleErrors(ModelAndView modelAndView){
        
        modelAndView.setViewName("account/login");
        return modelAndView;

    }
```

- configuration

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/handleLoginErrors").permitAll()
                //.failureUrl("/login?error=true")/**/
                .and()
                .build();
    }
```

However, the point is to return the errors to the registration page so that the user can see where he made a mistake during registration. That is, to return the user to the registration form and indicate errors in front of the fields where these errors were found.

Who has any ideas how to display errors anyway? And why is there an automatic redirection to /login, and not to the page you specified?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will, by default, redirect to login?error (GET)  whenever an error occurs. For login errors, you can, however, change that behaviour by specifying an endpoint (url) that'll handle the login errors. This is done by calling `failureUrl`.

```
 return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/handleLoginErrors")
            .and()
            .build();
```

You should also add a controller method matching handleLoginErrors.

```
 @GetMapping("/handleLoginErrors")
 ModelAndView handleErrors(ModelAndView){
  mv.addObject("loginStatus", "failed");
  mv.setViewName("loginError"); the view name i.e loginError.html
 return mv;

}
```

Spring also provides several mechanisms for generic error handling. More information can be found here https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the point is to return the errors to the registration page so that the user can see where he made a mistake during registration. That is, to return the user to the registration form and indicate errors in front of the fields where these errors were found. I indicated above what I tried to do. I already have something like on my page : <div th:if="${#fields.has any errors()}">
<ul>
                        <<li th:each="error : ${#fields.all Errors()}" th:text="${error}" />
</ul>

Comment: I tried it like this : <div class="alert warning-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                    <p th:each="error : ${#fields.error('*')}" th:text="${error}"></p>

Comment: despite that I explicitly specified the address to redirect to in case of an error, the redirect goes to the address -> /login

Comment: @skyho, are you're getting that exception in the first request to /POST register after the registration form has been processed ?What address have you spcified in case of an error (failureUrl is only used in case of a login error, not a general error)?

Comment: @skyho, also try to move the errors outside the form tag because they shouldn't be submitted anyway.

Comment: that's the point. the user fills out the form - Registration of a new user, then presses the Register button. Deserialization of the received form fields into a DTO takes placed and validation of the fields takes place. If the fields have errors, then the section with BindingResult.hasErrors() is triggered. And I need the user to be directed to the registration page again and see his mistakes on this page, opposite the field where he made them.

Comment: "...are you're getting that exception in the first request to /POST register after the registration form has been processed ?" - It's so.

Comment: For the Login page, if there are errors, then they were worked out normally, I had it specified initially.failure Url("/login?error=true"). The client saw what was wrong. I also need to reflect the errors on the registration form of a new client.

Comment: "...  also try to move the errors outside the form tag because they shouldn't be submitted anyway "  --- Then it also causes this error:   -- org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [ERROR] 10:56:19 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/account/register.html]")] with root cause

Comment: @skyho, can you try the syntax found in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895265/field-error-with-binding-when-using-thymeleaf-form-and-pass-to-controller (they're using * rather than $ )